# Struts2 Example/HelloWorld.action

Tags: java, struts2

I'm trying to set an html/jsp as my index page. I've set a home.html in the struts.xml. When I load the "localhost/appName/"  , it loads the home.html but it has "localhost/appName/example/HelloWorld.action" as the url. Is there anyways to get it to just show the home.html at the end?

Here is my struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <default-action-ref name="index" />

    <global-results>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"/>
    </global-exception-mappings>

    <action name="index">
        <result>/home.html</result>
    </action>
</package>

<!-- <include file="example.xml"/> -->

<!-- Add packages here -->
```

Comment: Don't access pages directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can configure your Index page in `web.xml` file. Include following configurations in `web.xml`

```
<web-app> 
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
        home.html
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<!-- your other configurations-->
</web-app>
```